# Scatter-plot of Numeric vs. String data from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the following form:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'l': [["c", "d"], ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["c", "d"], ["c", "d"]]})
```

The column `l` consists of lists, where the list-entries can either be in the set `{a,b,c,d}`. I want to plot the contents of `l` for each value of `t` in the following manner which basically shows which of the four possible values `{a,b,c,d}` are `acticated` at a time `t`:

[image]

In order to create the above plot, what I did was to create the following dataframe based on `df` above (`-1` is not activated, otherwise non-negative):

```
df_plot = pd.DataFrame({'t': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6],
                   'a': [-1, 0, -1, 0, -1,-1,-1],
                   'b': [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1,-1,-1],
                   'c': [2, -1, 2, -1, 2,2,2],
                   'd': [3, -1, 3, -1, 3,3,3]})

import numpy as np
ax = df_plot.plot(x="t", y=["a","b","c","d"],style='.', ylim=[-0.5,3.5], yticks=np.arange(0,3.1,1),legend=False)
labels = ["a","b","c","d"]
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

This technically gives me what I want, however, I'd like to think that there is an easier and more professional way to plot this - is there a smarter way using one of Python's libraries?

Comment: So you want to know out of all combinations, which have been activated at the same time at some point, is that right? So {a,b},{c,d}. Or you need it for each point `t`?

Comment: @yatu For each point `t` I just want to mark which one of `a`,`b`,`c` or `d` have been activated. All possible combinations are possible, it is merely due to my laziness that the example above only has `{a,b}` and `{c,d}`

Comment: Well you will end up having some discrete representation in any case,  your current solution seems fine to me.

Comment: @yatu Thanks - surprised there is no immediate way to do this automatically in any of Python's plotting libraries

Comment: @N08 If you are looking for something based just on Pandas check out my answer.

Comment: @N08 Hello, I just wanted to know if my answer worked out well for your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
# Reshape dataframe    
dff = df.l.apply(pd.Series).merge(df, right_index = True, left_index = True).drop(["l"], axis = 1).melt(id_vars = ['t'], value_name = "l").drop("variable", axis = 1)

# Plot dataframe
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(dff['t'], dff['l'])
# plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

More details about what is going on in the code i wrote can be found clicking this link : https://mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-split-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-rows-in-pandas-9849d8ff2401

**Note**: it should work no matter how many items you have in the lists in column *l*.